# Show/hide objects in layout based on spinner value

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I created a layout that has at the top of it a `Spinner` with two options: Camera and Gallery (shown as this green thing).

When the user clicks on camera I had like it to open beneath the spinner few more objects such as ImageView and buttons like this:

[image]

When the user clicks on Gallery I had like it to show like this:

[image]

My question is how can I move between these two layouts?

From my understanding, I can use

```
setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

Spinner spinner = findViewById( R.id.spinner);
if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("camera")) {
     setContentView( R.layout.camera);
} else { setContentView( R.layout.gallery); }
```

But how do I know when to initialize the objects? because if I will try to use

```
Button button = findViewById( R.id.button1);
```

when it has the content of the gallery layout it won't find it and I will get an error.

I know I can also place all of the objects in a single layout and play with the visibility of the objects but I was wondering if there is a smarter way to load objects based on user choice.

Thank you

Comment: As long as the layouts are simple and does't affect UI performance I would just keep the two layouts in same file and toogle visiblity of the layouts based on the spinner

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this, I would probably make a separate `Fragment` for each of your layouts (camera and gallery). Then in the main layout, you can put a `FrameLayout` below the `Spinner` and load the appropriate `Fragment` into that frame when an item in your `Spinner` is selected.